# Complexity class P - is $k$ only natural numbers?

Tags: computational-complexity

I think I have seen an algorithm that has $x^{1.5}$ as its complexity. However, according to Wikipedia, it states that the complexity class P is defined as $\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{N}} \mbox{DTIME}(n^k)$. So does this mean that only natural numbers are allowed in $k$ in the complexity class P? Or am I mistaken, and there is no algorithm that has rational number as $k$?

Thanks.

Comment: Note that $O(x^{1.5})=O(x^2)$.

Comment: I've always thought it was unfortunate that mathematicians used the $=$ sign instead of the $\subset$ or $\in$ sign to indicate that some quantity was $O(f(x))$, but never more so than now.

Comment: Sorry for an ambiguity in that notation. You're right. This bizarre *unequality* just looks like an ordinary equality, but this kind of usage is so common that it's hard for me to imagine any universal alternative. I know that algebraic number theorists use the notation $x^{1.5}\ll x^2$ and harmonic analysists use $x^{1.5}\lesssim x^2$, but not sure if it is universal also in complexity theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DTIME($n^{1.5}$) is the class of decision problems solvable by a Turing machine in time $O(n^{1.5})$.

DTIME($n^2$) is the class of decision problems solvable by a Turing machine in time $O(n^2)$.

Any function that is $O(n^{1.5})$ is also $O(n^2)$, so DTIME($n^{1.5}$) is a subset of DTIME($n^2$), and therefore is contained in $P$ as well.

In general, if $f(x)$ is any function at all such that there are $k$ and $n$ with $f(x) < kx^n$ for all sufficiently large $x$, then $f(x)$ is $O(x^n)$, and an algorithm that takes $f(x)$ steps for an input of size $x$ will be in $P$.  This includes, for example, algorithms with time complexity $ x^e (\log x)^2 + 37x\cos\left(x^2\right) + \hbox{phase of the moon}$.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, you must be careful about notations such as $DTIME(n^{r})$, when $r$ is an arbitrary real number. The reason is that the function $n \rightarrow n^r$ or $n \rightarrow \lfloor n^r \rfloor$ may no longer be computable. (As there are uncountably many reals, but only countably many Turing machines).